# How to return a column value based on integer index and another column value in pandas?

Tags: pandas, function, apply

I have a `df` that I want to groupby `Date` and apply a function to it.

```
          Date      Symbol    Shares 
0   1990-01-01      A         0.0        
1   1990-01-01      B         0.0        
2   1990-01-01      C         0.0         
3   1990-01-01      D         0.0  
4   1990-01-02      A         50.0     
5   1990-01-02      B         100.0      
6   1990-01-02      C         66.0      
7   1990-01-02      D         7.0       
8   1990-01-03      A         11.0      
9   1990-01-03      B         123.0      
10  1990-01-03      C         11.0      
11  1990-01-03      D         11.0
```

I should be able to access the `Shares` value for a `Symbol` from the previous `Date` in the function. How can I do that? Creating `df[prev_shares]` like `df.groupby('Symbol')['Shares'].shift(1)` before applying the function is not an option because the function calculates `Shares` row by row. 
 It should look like:

```
def calcs(x):
    x.loc[some_condition, 'Shares'] = ...
    x.loc[other_condition, 'Shares'] = # return 'Shares' from previous 'Date' for this 'Symbol'

df = df.groupby('Date').apply(calcs)
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I post the function that I created.

```
Equity = 10000

def calcs(x):

    global Equity

    if x.index[0]==0: return x

    x.loc[x['condition'] == True, 'Shares'] = np.floor((Equity * 0.02 / x['ATR']).astype(float))

    x.loc[x['condition'] == False, 'Shares'] = # locate Symbol for the previous Date and return its Shares value

    x['Closed_P/L'] = x['Shares'] * x['Close']
    Equity += x['Closed_P/L'].sum()

    return x

data = data.groupby('Date').apply(calcs)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please share your expected output.

Comment: What are you tying to do, other than access the last Shares value? By clearer with what you are trying to accomplish please.

Comment: I edited the question and added the full version of my function.

Comment: Please read this before posting a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I basically tried to simplify a problem in this question because I posted my original problem to SO but i haven't received any answer to that. Here is the link to the original problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299778/how-to-forward-fill-row-values-with-function-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe

Comment: @mmaarrttoonn, ok, I'll take a look later on.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC something like this might help, although what you're trying to accomplish in the end is unclear. Below you will find the data grouped by 'Symbol' and 'Date'. Column 'diff' shows the incremental P/L.

please advise what you need additionally.

```
df =  data.set_index(['Symbol', 'Date']).sort_index()[['Shares']]
df['diff'] = np.nan
idx = pd.IndexSlice

for ix in df.index.levels[0]:
    df.loc[ idx[ix,:], 'diff'] = df.loc[idx[ix,:], 'Shares' ].diff()

df.fillna(0)

                   Shares   diff
Symbol Date                     
A      1990-01-01     0.0    0.0
       1990-01-02    50.0   50.0
       1990-01-03    11.0  -39.0
B      1990-01-01     0.0    0.0
       1990-01-02   100.0  100.0
       1990-01-03   123.0   23.0
C      1990-01-01     0.0    0.0
       1990-01-02    66.0   66.0
       1990-01-03    11.0  -55.0
D      1990-01-01     0.0    0.0
       1990-01-02     7.0    7.0
       1990-01-03    11.0    4.0
```